# ManyToMany Field on Django Admin Interface

Tags: django, rest, many-to-many, admin

On Django Rest, I have a many to many relation for a field of material list. Instances of materials are added in a loan model. It works, to add through the admin site but the display is  disintuitive: Instances are mixed with materials (instances are in parenthesis).
It's possible to have to separated list ? One to select materials and one other to add/remove instances linked to materials ?
[image: r]

Comment: The parenthesis are because that is the `__str__` of your model.

Comment: So what sort of widget do you want? A list of checkboxes?

Comment: Thanks, i want two list: one with materials and one other for instance of materials selected depending on the relation

Answer (score 0):

The name that it shows in the list are the results of the `__str__` method on your model. So if you want to display something else, you can alter the `__str__` method. For example if this is a model `Material` with a `name`  field, you can set it to:

```
class Material(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128, unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

You can set the [**`filter_horizontal`** attribute [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.filter_horizontal):

```
from django.contrib import admin

@admin.register(MyModel)
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    # …
    filter_horizontal = ('materials_field_name',)
```

this thus will use a widget with two lists where you can move to the right and the left.

Comment: Is the filter attribute inherit from ModelAdmin ? Cause i have registered an inline Tab with an other inline field for generic materials

Comment: I have tried, but the instances materials are not filtered after selected material on the left column